# How to have a reponsive and neatly aligned image gallery when the images are different sizes/ratios?

Tags: css

Hoping you can help me with this. This is a common problem in general but the solutions I am finding from Google aren't working for me in my specific case because they cause unintended side effects or do not allow for all the functionality I want. Take a look at this code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.libraryThumbnail img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.libraryThumbnail {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 3px;
  float: left;
  margin: 6px 0;
  width: 10%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 11.11%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 12.5%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 14.28%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 33%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image One
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Two
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Three
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Four
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Five
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Six
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Seven
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Eight
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Nine
</div>
<div class="libraryThumbnail">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png"> Image Ten
</div>
```

This is the behavior I want. Notice how the images scale up and down in between break points and a row always takes up the full width of the browser. And of course, everything is nice and neat.

Now let's replace the images with some that are each slightly different in dimensions and aspect ratio. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZmQWj And stuff starts breaking. How would I go about getting the first behavior with these images? Stretching is less than ideal but honestly I would be okay with it because I know in advance that all the images will be close enough to the same size that it won't be too noticeable. But ideally, each image would be centered in its div and blank space would fill in the gaps. Again I have found a number of different ways to do this by Googling relevant phrases, but none of them are working quite right for me and I don't know CSS well enough to understand exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer:**

replace `float: right` with `display: inline-block`.

**Explanation:**

Since the your images are in different `height`. That's why `float: left` may work strangely.

`display: inline-block` could do the job since the `inline-block` would wrap itself and align to left.

**Alternative**

You may try on `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

Might try this approach: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVKxam

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.libraryThumbnail img {
  height: 97%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.libraryThumbnail {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0;
  padding: 15% 3px 0;
  margin: 6px 0;
  flex-basis: 9.9%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 11.11%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 12.5%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 14.28%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 16.66%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 33%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .libraryThumbnail {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me but I ended up using a CSS grid with flexboxes as the image containers:

```
.libraryGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10em, 0fr));
  grid-gap: 1em;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.libraryThumbnail {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.libraryThumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMjXjM

Based off this snippet from css-tricks https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-grid-starter-layouts/#grid-fit-as-needed